# Compilation error using PendingIntent

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-pendingintent

So I'm working on a chunk of code that will allow me to run an app out of the Status bar at the top I'm a good way into it and almost finished. I just need a second opinion on why my "PendingIntent.getActivity(this,that,next,thing);" Its not compiling.
Here's the code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NotifyMe extends Activity {
NotificationManager nm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent MainActivity = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pi = new PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    String body = "Simple message";
    String title = "Hello World";
    Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.note, body, System.currentTimeMillis());
    n.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, body, pi);

}
}
```

So I might be doing this all wrong, any tips in this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is not a real question, or i missed it

Comment: I guess the question would be "What is wrong that the pending intent is highlighted in red"  I'll fix it.

Comment: Try hovering over the red (if its in eclipse) and it will tell you.  Are you using eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 PendingIntent pi = new PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Dont need new.

More importantly, you need to focus on getting your eclipse environment setup so that you can at least view the error messages.  They should occur in an area called Problems, and when you report an error on StackOverflow you can include what the error message is.   Let us know if you have questions about your environment.

Comment: Oh yeah I have all of that set up, thanks for the tip and sorry for the newb error :(

Answer (score 0):

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(FancyDiamondResultActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
```