# Cross API Notifications

Tags: android, notifications

So this is more or less a continuation of my last question [Link to last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530830/compilation-error-using-pendingintent)

I have been working on the code and a buddy of mine suggested I use Notifiction.Builder so I have that figured out. I am wondering how I or anyone else would go about making status notifications "Cross API" What I mean by this is that Builder works on API 11+ but anything below is a no go. Are there any known work around's / fixes for this issue or Will I need to code two different versions of this?

Comment: Actually both answers are pretty good there, or so they seem. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to achieve multiple api support using deprecated methods, the most frequently mentioned of which is reflection. Personally, I went with exploiting the classloader to solve the notification problem. I made a base abstract class with basic wrapper methods for handling the different data required for creating a notification, which looks like this:

```
public abstract class NotificationWrapper {

public NotificationWrapper(Context context) {

}

public abstract void createNotification(int resid, CharSequence ticker);

public abstract void setTitle(CharSequence title);

public abstract void setText(CharSequence text);

public abstract void setIntent(PendingIntent intent);

public abstract void setFlags(int... flags);

public abstract void setDefaults(int defaults);

public abstract Notification getNotification();
}
```

You can of course add and remove methods depending on how much you're customizing your notifications. Then you can just extend this to three separate classes: one for API <11, one for API >=11, and one for Jelly Bean and up. In each class you just relay these method calls to the appropriate available methods for the current API version (i.e. pre-11 relays to Notification methods, post-11 relays to Notification.Builder methods, and Jelly Bean is the same as post-11 except it uses build() as opposed to getNotification()). Then, when it comes time to create your notification you can use a conditional on the SDK version and the beauties of polymorphism to load the right subclass and build your notification using its wrapper methods:

```
NotificationWrapper wrapper = null;
int ver = VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (ver >= 16) {
    wrapper = new NotificationWrapJB(context);
} else if (ver >= 11) {
    wrapper = new NotificationWrapHC(context);
} else {
    wrapper = new NotificationWrapPreHC(context);
}
wrapper.createNotification(resId, tickerText);
//etc....
```

Again, this is just one of many ways to deal with this problem, but I like it because it just feels more organized.

If you're unfamiliar with which methods to use for the different SDK versions, read the Android docs on [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) and [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html).

Comment: Sweet, thanks for that! I'm going to give this a shot here soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) present in the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html). 
And if you're looking for the brand New Notifications coming with Jelly Bean you can use [NotificationCompat2](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NotificationCompat2) from Jake Wharton (the one that made ActionBarSherlock).